# What all statements can be executed inside `List`s, like `[ if(true), for(;;) ]`

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist

I know of, `for(;;)` loops, `if(true)` conditions, and ternary operators (`(true)?1:2`), but

I'm curious, that what all statements can be executed inside the `List` initialization `[]`, like `[ if(true), for(;;) ]`,

Thanking you...

Comment: No *statements* can be executed in collection literals.  You can execute *expressions* and "elements".  See [Bob Nystrom's article explaining collection-`for` and collection-`if`](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c).

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to the ever helping and humble @jamesdlin for this answer via comment.

All the **expressions** are supported, like:

1. for loops: `for(;;)`
2. if condition: `if(true)`
3. ternary operator: `(true)?1:2`
4. spread operator: `...['1', '2', '3']`
5. `(x + y)`
6. `function(argument)`

etc.

[source](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c)

Comment: Er, *all* expressions can be used, and there are many more expressions than that.  For example, `x + y` is an expression, as is `f()`, etc.

Comment: sorry, please forgive this newcomer